# JS code to have multiple functions be applied to a cell on edit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently trying to write some JS in script editor on a google sheet to not only produce a timestamp in conjunction with a check box being clicked but also set a timer that if the box is check for more than X minutes the cell will start to turn red.

Also when I uncheck the box to make the cell green.  The idea behind this is think of a restaurant hostess paradigm when I click the box that means table is full timestamp gives me the time the box was checked and color shows its not available - IF I uncheck box it gives time stamp it was unchecked while also resetting time counter and changing the cell back to green.  Currently I can get the timestamp portion to work with the code I wrote and it to change color on the first edit but it will not vacillate between colors based on the check box

Below is the code I currently have.  Would a trigger function or another on edit function be used If anyone has any tips or ideas it would be greatly appreciated

- For visual each column i'm referencing is a stagnate column 1 which is seat number the check boxes going down the 2nd column and the 3rd column which is populating what time the box is checked and unchecked

```js
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (s.getName() == "Sheet1") { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if (r.getColumn() == 5) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      //if( nextCell.getValue() !== '' ) //is empty?
      nextCell.setValue(new Date().setFontColor('green');
      }
```

Comment: ** imagine column is 2 so seat numbers would be to the left and time stamps would be to the right disregard the if value is empty code as I want it to change on each action wether its checked off or not and then perform the subsequent timestamp and associated color

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // the active sheet (no need to check if the sheet == sheet1 as the active sheet will always be the one that's being edited)
  var r = e.range; // the range of the edited cell
  var c = r.getColumn(); // the column of the range
  var timeDelay = 5; // number in seconds
  var checkbox = r.getValue(); // the value of the checkbox after being edited
  var date = new Date(); // the date for the timestamp

  if (c == 5 && checkbox == true) { // if the checkbox has been checked, change the color to red
    var nextCell = r.offset(0,1);
    Utilities.sleep(timeDelay * 1000); // Utilities.sleep takes a number in milliseconds
    nextCell.setValue(date).setBackground("red");
  } else if (c == 5 && checkbox == false) { // if the checkbox has been unchecked, change the color to green
    var nextCell = r.offset(0,1);
    nextCell.setValue(date).setBackground("green");
  }
}
```

I made a few changes to yours, some are simply personal preference of what I think is more readable in the long run if you were to add more to the code (i.e. declaring the date beforehand, setting all your variables up at the start, etc.).

However, this is definitely superfluous as active sheet will return the right thing anyway:

```
 if (s.getName() == "Sheet1")
```

I also changed setFontColor() to setBackground() as it sounded like this is what you wanted from your description and thought you might not know of the function, although you can of course change it back to setFontColor() without any issues.

I also added in the time delay which you asked about, although I'm not sure why you'd need it in this context. If this isn't what you were talking about, feel free to remove these two lines and the rest of the code will still work fine:

```
var timeDelay = 5; // number in seconds
```

and

```
   Utilities.sleep(timeDelay * 1000);
```

Comment: Hey thank you this has some really cool functions I have not used before.  The reason for the delay is if its green too long it will start to turn to a different color accentuating for example someone has been seated at that table over lets say 1 hour to give the hostess a heads up does this make sense?  Also is it possible to have the return values of time stamps and color on a separate sheet from the  checkboxes?

Comment: ^^^ Also is it possible that when I un click  the box it resets the color back to blank and just leaves the timestamp or better yet clears the whole cell to blank?

Comment: Not to pile on with more questions but Also I added a second If statement that I want if un clicked immediately turn green and if its green for lets say more than 5 min it will turn ready to signal ready for another customer.  In addition to if its clicked for too long say 30+ min it will turn red.  So a cascade of 3 different scenarios 3 different colors

Comment: Also how does it know that e is just returning a cell im not following that logic I understand the nesting of the range to get to the column but what specific identifies e as just a single cell?  I normally see functions empty or with a return value so this is a bit confusing to me.  Thanks again for the help on all this!

Comment: Getting this to output would be very easy, all you'd need is to define a new sheet and set the output to work to that sheet (i.e. `var outputSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Output")`). Leaving them blank instead of using a timestamp is as easy as updating with just "" instead of the date.

Comment: I think for most of your other questions this is changing the question substantially! Not sure I can answer them all in comments, can you mark this one as correct and ask a new question with the different parts please?

Comment: Attached is the spread sheet if giving a visual provides more context and visibility into the issue I am trying to solve -  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V6Up9JpjGXAFBpxYybQtMXoE6B6pZCHlO0vbC5URqQ0/edit#gid=21951357

Comment: Each table is represented by a check box which must complete the all three functions based on time and represented by color changes

Comment: Could you please explain a little more why I am passing through e instead of leaving the function blank.  Where in the code does it know that e means only a single edited cell and defining the range besides the comment saying that is the case?

Comment: onEdit requires you to pass in something (in this case e) for it to be able to manipulate the thing that's being edited. I'm happy to answer this in a new question but this is slightly beyond the scope of the initial question - would you be able to mark this one as correct and send me a link to the new one please?